# Geocoder Gem - can not search nearbys or near (undefined method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, search, rubygems

I am trying to use Geocoder gem but having an issue on search part. First of all, I have a Location Model with;

```
create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "address"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.string   "location_type"
    t.integer  "boat_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
```

I added gem 'geocoder' to my gem file and locations model;

```
geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?
```

Then I implemented [this tutorial](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/draggable.html) to save address, longitude and latitude to my database. Now I would like to put a search box to root page and redirect users to index page, where near locations will be shown.

So here is my search box at root page; (This is `main.html.erb`)

```
<%= form_tag locations_path, :method => :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search Near", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Then it sends `params` to `locations_controller` `#index` action;

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController

  def index

    if params[:search].present?
    @locations = Location.near(params[:search], 15)
  else
    @locations = Location.all
  end
  end


end
```

After, I have an `index.html.erb` to show the near locations;

```
<h3>Nearby locations</h3>
<ul>
<% @locations.each do |location| %>
  <li><%=location.address %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

So it works when I type the full address (as saved in database), for instance, the address in database is : `Fenerbahçe Yat Limanı, Kadıköy, Türkiye`,
when I search: `Fenerbahçe Yat Limanı`, I can see the result but if I only Search: `Fenerbahçe`, it returns nil.

I dont understand why and do not know how I can make it autocomplete or so. 
I wonder if that might happen because I use tutorial to save address, latitude and longitude and gem has its own way converting it and it does not match.Is that possible?

Here is the log when I search a keyword;

```
Started GET "/locations?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Fenerbah%C3%A7e" for ::1 at 2015-05-12 16:11:03 +0300
Processing by LocationsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"Fenerbahçe"}
  Location Load (0.3ms)  SELECT locations.*, (69.09332411348201 * ABS(locations.latitude - 36.7252955) * 0.7071067811865475) + (59.836573914187355 * ABS(locations.longitude - 24.4447587) * 0.7071067811865475) AS distance, CASE WHEN (locations.latitude >= 36.7252955 AND locations.longitude >= 24.4447587) THEN  45.0 WHEN (locations.latitude <  36.7252955 AND locations.longitude >= 24.4447587) THEN 135.0 WHEN (locations.latitude <  36.7252955 AND locations.longitude <  24.4447587) THEN 225.0 WHEN (locations.latitude >= 36.7252955 AND locations.longitude <  24.4447587) THEN 315.0 END AS bearing FROM "locations" WHERE (locations.latitude BETWEEN 36.00163658444576 AND 37.44895441555424 AND locations.longitude BETWEEN 23.541891160028793 AND 25.34762623997121)  ORDER BY distance ASC
  Rendered locations/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 629ms (Views: 273.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
  [1]: http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/draggable.html
```

Here is my database;

```
 <Location id: 11, address: "Fenerbahçe Yat Limanı, Kadıköy, Türkiye", longitude: 29.037873999999988, latitude: 40.970286, location_type: nil, boat_id: 248, created_at: "2015-05-12 08:23:43", updated_at: "2015-05-12 08:23:43">
```

So to escape this situation, is there a way to implement autofill option to main page instead of geocoder?. or combine them?

**EDIT 1**:

So I manage to add autocomplete option but, geocoder still does not work properly do not know why. if I type New York for instance it finds in the database, but if I type new yoek it does not find anything. It should normally converts it right?. Maybe my Location model is wrong. I do not know how address should be saved to database or does that matter?